# Approximate sum with binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Is there an efficient way to compute

$\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i} / i$

I tried to look at some properties of the binomial coefficient to get rid of the $1/i$, but it seems there is no closed solution. Can I use an approximation?

Ok, I found the normal approximation:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi np(1 - p)}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\exp(\frac{-(i - np)^2}{(2 np(1 - p))})/i$

which is good enough for me.

Comment: Approximation as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: No, actually I need the finite sums for different $n$. Thanks for the hint, I will check it. I would also like to understand how to get from the sum to the integral.

Comment: I would aim to work out cumulative distribution of a variation on Poisson distribution obtained via Poisson limit theorem. Will answer if managed.